# How to integrate Google game play services in Kotlin Android and retrieve Leaderboard and Achievements

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to kotlin and I want to tried out Google game play services. I am stuck at on google sign in function. I clicked sign-in button, and it shows being clicked, but the UI did not change to google account log in window.  What does this line do? and how can I show the sign-in window when the game starts?

**Main Activity:**

```
package com.example.spotifygame

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.isInvisible
import com.google.android.gms.games.*
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
import com.google.android.gms.games.PlayGamesSdk;


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    //UI Buttons
    private lateinit var signInButton: Button
    private lateinit var achievementButton: Button
    private lateinit var leaderBoardButton: Button
    //Game service Clients
    private lateinit var gamesSignInClient: GamesSignInClient
    private lateinit var achievementsClient: AchievementsClient
    private lateinit var leaderboardsClient: LeaderboardsClient



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //google game services
        PlayGamesSdk.initialize(this);

        // Buttons wire
        signInButton = findViewById(R.id.signIn)
        achievementButton = findViewById(R.id.achievements)
        leaderBoardButton = findViewById(R.id.leader_board)

        //verify user authentication
        initGoogleServiceClients()

        //default Buttons invisible
        signInButton.isInvisible = true
        achievementButton.isInvisible = true
        leaderBoardButton.isInvisible = true

        // setup button functions
        signInButton.setOnClickListener() {
            println("debug: sign btn clicked")
            gamesSignInClient.signIn()
        }
        achievementButton.setOnClickListener() {
            println("debug: achievement btn clicked")

            showAchievements()
        }
        leaderBoardButton.setOnClickListener() {
            println("debug: leader board btn clicked")
            showTopPlayers()
        }
    }

    private fun initGoogleServiceClients() {
        gamesSignInClient = PlayGames.getGamesSignInClient(this)
        gamesSignInClient.isAuthenticated.addOnCompleteListener { isAuthenticatedTask: Task<AuthenticationResult> ->

            // boolean = successfully authenticated
            val isAuthenticated = isAuthenticatedTask.isSuccessful &&
                    isAuthenticatedTask.result.isAuthenticated
            if (isAuthenticated) {
                // Continue with Play Games Services
                // get two clients
                achievementsClient = PlayGames.getAchievementsClient(this)
                leaderboardsClient = PlayGames.getLeaderboardsClient(this)

                // make buttons visible
                achievementButton.isInvisible = false
                leaderBoardButton.isInvisible = false

                //show current player ID
                PlayGames.getPlayersClient(this).currentPlayer.addOnCompleteListener { mTask: Task<Player?>? ->
                    val iD = mTask?.result?.playerId
                    println("debug: id is $iD")
                }
                //debug
                println("debug: successfully authenticated")

            } else {
                // Disable your integration with Play Games Services or show a
                // login button to ask  players to sign-in. Clicking it should
                // call GamesSignInClient.signIn().
                gamesSignInClient.signIn()

                //make sign in button visible
                signInButton.isInvisible = false

                //debug
                println("debug: failed authenticated")
            }
        }

    }

    // Button Functions
    fun showTopPlayers() {
        leaderboardsClient.allLeaderboardsIntent.addOnSuccessListener {
            //deprecated
            startActivityForResult(intent,0)

            //new way
//            val previewRequest =
//                registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
//                    if (it.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
//                        val list = it.data
//                        // do whatever with the data in the callback
//                        println("debug: data list have $list")
//
//                    }
//                }
        }

    }
    fun showAchievements() {
        achievementsClient.achievementsIntent.addOnSuccessListener {
            startActivityForResult(intent,0)

        }
    }

    // Feature Functions

    fun unlockAchievements(achievementID: String) {
        // unlock the achievement
        achievementsClient.unlock(achievementID)
    }

    fun updateScore(leaderboardID: String, score: Long) {
        leaderboardsClient.submitScore(leaderboardID, score)

    }


}
```

I am also not sure how to call show leaderboard and achievement in functions. I am using deprecated code startActivityForResults.

**Gradle(:app)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'

}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.spotifygame'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.spotifygame"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    //google play games
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games-v2:+"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.3.0'


}
```

**terminal and UI capture:**

```
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (10405) for package com.example.spotifygame ----------------------------
2022-11-11 00:15:52.449 10405-10405 System.out              com.example.spotifygame              I  debug: failed authenticated
2022-11-11 00:15:54.992 10405-10405 System.out              com.example.spotifygame              I  debug: sign btn clicked
```

I followed google play games service android document. I have set up the project in google game console. for my gradle file, I did not include allproject scope since it gives me error.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
      google()
      mavenCentral()
    }
  }
```

link:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart

Youtube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NwJkoI3IIWo&t=427s

I expect:
There will be a google game account sign in window when I run the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel your pain, Google have provided no code on how to use `implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games-v2:+"`.  This is in Java (with lambdas), so just copy/paste into Android Studio in a Kotlin file and it will translate it.

I'll get you half way there as my code is so different I don't want to try to work it into what you have.  This shows the achievements already accomplished by the player.  We're assuming `PlayGamesSdk.initialize(this);` loaded without errors (the logcat doesn't have `**** APP NOT CORRECTLY CONFIGURED TO USE GOOGLE PLAY GAME SERVICES **** DEVELOPER_ERROR` etc.) and

```
    GamesSignInClient gamesSignInClient = PlayGames.getGamesSignInClient(this);
    gamesSignInClient.isAuthenticated().addOnCompleteListener(isAuthenticatedTask -> {
      if (isAuthenticatedTask.isSuccessful() && isAuthenticatedTask.getResult().isAuthenticated())
```

is true!  (Do I need mention that be aware of where you use `this`? If its in a runner it may not be the context needed for passed parameter.)

Here is my show achievements, the routine called when the UI Achievements button is pressed: -

```
private void showAchievements() {
    try {
        AchievementsClient ac = PlayGames.getAchievementsClient(this);
        Task<Intent> ti = ac.getAchievementsIntent();
        ti.addOnSuccessListener(intent -> startActivityForResult(intent, 0));
    } catch (Exception | Error e) {
        //log error / whatever
    }
}
```

This could be a one-liner, I just broke it up with variables for easier reading.
Note the `Task` is an async that returns the intent you want to launch, it's not the intent itself.  So put a listener on complete of the task to get that intent to start the activity.

Use this approach for all of these routines which return a `Task<Intent>`.

Hope this helps!